# How to display texture with its original width and height

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'd like to display the texture that its size is 2880 * 2160 on 3840 * 2160 size of Monitor.

How should I set up the Unity, if I'd like to keep the original size of texture. Must the texture of size be a power of 2 in the first place?

I still don't really understand about Quad Scale and Camera Size, and so on.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Please rephrase it.

Comment: I apologize for any confusion.  Addtional Information:The MainCamera  is orthographic.  
<Question1>  
How much do i have to set Quad Scale?  
<Question2>  
Do i have to change the texture size from 2880 * 2160 to 2048 * 2048?  
<Question3>  
How much do i have to set Camera orthographicSize?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I'm trying to do is display Texture on the screen in the same size as original texture size.(I'd not like to scale)

Comment: I tried to push "This answer is useful".  This is my first time using stack overflow.  Was it too much trouble?

Comment: I understood it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How should i set up the Unity, if i'd like to keep the original size
>   of texture.

To keep the-same size, you have to do it **without** a Quad.

**1**.Select your Texture, change the Texture Type to Sptite (2D and UI)

**2**.Go to GameObject->2D Object-> Sprite.

**3**.Select the new Sprite you just created and plug in your Texture to the Sprite Slot of the Sprite Renderer.

This will not resize the Texture in any way.

> Must the texture of size be a power of 2 in the first place?

It's always recommended to make your Texture size be a power of 2 in every game engine and this still apply here.